# After stubbing function still it calls the real function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have stubbed the content of file, so I can run through only outer function

**file.html**

```
<body onload ="test('file.txt')">
<body>
```

**file.js**

```
    const fs1 = require('fs');
    let param;
    module.export = {
         test,
         test1,
         param
    }

    function test (outputParam) {
      let fileData = test1(outputParam);
      param = fileData;
    }

    function test1(outputParam) {
       let data = fs1.readFileSync(outputParam);
       return data; 
    }
```

Here as you see I load function test from html onload and in turn test1 calls and reads file, I have stubbed this file content as shown in the test below

When I run the test I want to see the variable param has the file content value

**test.spec.js**

```
    let sinon = require("sinon");
    let filejs = require('./file.js');

    it('should run only the outer function' ,function() {

    // I try to stub my function here
    sinon.stub(filejs,'test1').callsFake ((someArg) => {
      return "this is my file content";
    });

        // Now I will call my test function
        filejs.test(someArg);

    })
```

As you seen above I have stubbed function test1, still when I run the test I see test1 gets called and it reads the real file.

I am using mocha , I am new to stub or mock concepts, any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Let me know If you did not understand my question

Comment: `sinon.stub()` can only affect the properties of the export object but the `test()` function calls the internal function `test1()` directly. `sinon.stub()` can’t do anything about the internals of a module.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to stub `readFileSync`.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// ...

sinon.stub(fs, "readFileSync").callsFake ((someArg) => {
  return "this is my file content";
});
```

Besides that, I can spot two issues with your code.

- The *real* `readFileSync` will return a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) if called without a second parameter, not a string like your stub does.
- The body onload event only exists inside the DOM. The `fs` module is only available in Node.js. If you run your code in a browser, you won't be able to use `fs.readFileSync`. If you run it in Node, your HTML file and the onload event won't be useful.

Comment: If you run it in Node, your HTML file and the onload event won't be useful. you mean I should run it as         node file.js

Comment: If you are writing an app for Node, then yes. If your app is for the browser, there are other ways to read files I would consider.

Comment: Hi do you have any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299439/how-to-check-the-property-value-after-mocking-a-function-assertion-error-moch