# How to check the property value after mocking a function : Assertion Error ,mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

As per suggestion in question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297654/after-stubbing-function-still-it-calls-the-real-function) I mock readFileSync and mocked my outer function now I want to verify if the variables value is set as expected or not

**file.js**

```
    const fs1 = require('fs');
    let param;
    module.export = {
         test,
         param
    }

    function test (outputParam) {
     param = fs1.readFileSync(outputParam);
    }
```

I have stubbed this readFileSync and it returns specified file content as shown in the test below

When I run the test I want to see the variable param has the file content value

**test.spec.js**

```
    let expect = require('chai').expect;
    let fs = require("fs");
    let sinon = require("sinon");
    let filejs = require('./file.js');


    it('should run only the outer function and test if variable param is set to `this is my file content` ' ,function() {

     let someArg ="file.xml";

     sinon.stub(fs,'readFileSync').callsFake ((someArg) => {
        return "this is my file content";
      });

      var mock = sinon.mock(filejs);
      mock.expects('test').withArgs(someArg);
      expect(filejs.param).to.equal('this is my file content');

  })
```

From file.js, As you see property param gets value from "readFileSync" which is stubbed to return a value

When I run the test

> expect(filejs.param).to.equal('this is my file content');
>
> AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'this is my file content'

Comment: Hi Let me know if anyone hasn't understood my question

Comment: I have edited my question, made it more simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the correct spelling of `module.exports` - not `module.export`.

In your file.js the variable `param` is not initialized, so it will get the value `undefined` and will be exported with that value, too. The exported value does not change if you modify `param` later. An export only binds a property to a value, not to a variable. And in fact, you don't even need a local variable. To change the value of an export dynamically, at least in Node, you simply reassign the property on `module.exports`.

```js
const fs1 = require('fs');

module.exports = {
     test
}

function test (outputParam) {
    module.exports.param = fs1.readFileSync(outputParam);
}
```

As for your test.spec.js, you were already very close to get it to work. After stubbing the method(s) that should not be called under the hub, just call your `test` function, passing real parameters. No mock is required there.

```js
let expect = require('chai').expect;
let fs = require("fs");
let sinon = require("sinon");
let filejs = require('./file.js');


it('should run only the outer function and test if variable param is set to `this is my file content` ' ,function() {

 let someArg ="file.xml";

 sinon.stub(fs,'readFileSync').callsFake ((someArg) => {
    return "this is my file content";
  });

  filejs.test(someArg);

  expect(filejs.param).to.equal('this is my file content');

});
```

Comment: Thanks GOTO 0, I want to understand how do we differentiate property and variable, in this case for 'param'

Comment: I understood properties are something related to a object and variable is like placeholder for value. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Glad I could help. There are some good articles all over the web explaining the fundamentals of variables and object properties in JS. I quickly googled out [this one](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/) which should cover your question. Good luck!